# Jupyter Class in different notebook?

Tags: python, class, oop, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

i am currently forced in an project to work with jupyter notebook, before I just used PyCharm. 
So I create a project and would like to add some classes to it. Should I write all of them in the one main notebook or create different notebooks for each class? 
As far as I understand, jupyter is not made for using several notebooks for one project (but I thnink there are options) but if I want to use some of my classes more general for other projects it does not make sense to not have it in a seperate notebook right?

I am sorry, maybe I have a basic misunderstanding of jupyter but I could not figure out yet, what is the best way.

Comment: You can `import yourpackage` from a jupyter notebook. In the same directory as the notebook you can put the code for that in `yourpackage.py`. Normal python packaging rules apply (ie. `__init__.py` and subdirectories)

Comment: ok, so it is not seen as "bad programming" in jupyter if i use several notbooks?

Comment: Well you aren't using "several notebooks." Notebooks are `*.ipynb` files. `*.py` are just regular python files, not notebooks. But no that is fine. That's actually better because you reuse code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jupyter will happily allow you to use multiple libraries in other notebooks. You can find the documents [here](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Notebook/Importing%20Notebooks.html)
Though if you want to move the project out to a command line executable, you may want to consider exporting the notebooks as .py files and then importing them as standard python libraries. Jupyter has a [nbconvert](https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert) method for this.

I do this a lot and ended up writing a small script that adds appropriate hashbang lines and strips out any Jupyter "magic" commands. You can find it at [github](https://github.com/txoof/develtools).

Usage: `./nbconvert myNotebook.ipynb`

There are also some excellent Jupyter magic commands that make working with libraries much easier.

```
# cause chagnged modules to be reloaded at execution
# add this to any notebook that sources an external .py file
%load_ext autoreload
%autoreload 2
```

I also find this useful:

```
# set %magic alias to convert the current notebook into a .py file
%alias nbconvert ~/devtools/nbconvert thisNotebook.ipynb
```

Usage:

```
%nbconvert
[NbConvertApp] Converting notebook searchTools.ipynb to python
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you for the detailed answer, now I also understand what Imtinan Azhar wanted to tell me.

Comment: In that same git repo is a script that will set up a per-project virtualenv using pipenv that will work with jupyter. Make sure you have pipenv and jupyter installed using pip before using it.

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessarily need notebooks, you may create .py files with your class implementations for example myclass.py, and then just normally do `import myclass`